# problem in use batchNormalization in the first layer with tensorflow 2.2

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, incompatibility

I need to use batchnormalization in the first layer and still use tensorflow 2.2, as the place where the trained network model will be sent has a tensorflow of 2.2 and cannot be updated.
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2QdI.png)

There is no problem running the code for tf>=2.3.0, but it is incompatible elsewhere. Would anyone know how to normalize the first layer with BatchNormalization and using tensorflow 2.2?
[Problem with tensorflow 2.2.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePnt6.png)

[To TF>=2.3.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctako.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My question has been solved in root cern forum. To run, I use HTCondor (a cluster) and I used:
#!/bin/bash
source /cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/views/LCG_96py3cu10/x86_64-centos7-gcc7-opt/setup.sh
cd /afs/cern.ch/work/f/fassunca/private/

this use "ancient version" tensorflow (1.14), so I changed to:
source /cvmfs/sft.cern.ch/lcg/views/LCG_98py3cu10/x86_64-centos7-gcc8-opt/setup.sh
In this source, the tensorflow is 2 and compatibility with all versions .
thank you to everybody